# How to remove a character from element and the corresponding character in another element in a list?

Tags: python, list, character, del

```
Sample = ['A$$N','BBBC','$$AA']
```

I need to compare every element to every other element in the list. So compare `sample[0]` and `sample[1]`, `sample[0]`, and `sample[2]`, `sample[1]` and `sample[2]`.

If any pair in the comparison has `$`, then `$`, and the corresponding element needs to be eliminated.

For example in:

```
sample[0] and sample[1]    Output1 : ['AN','BC']
sample[0] and sample[2]    Output2 : ['N', 'A']
sample[1] and sample[2]    Output3 : ['BC','AA']
```

```
for i in range(len(sample1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(sample1)):
        if i == "$" or j == "$":
            #Need to remove "$" and the corresponding element in the other list

   #Print the pairs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most beautiful code but will do the job.

```
from itertools import combinations
sample = ['A$$N','BBBC','$$AA']
output = []
for i, j in combinations(range(len(sample)), 2):
    out = ['', '']
    for pair in zip(sample[i], sample[j]):
        if '$' not in pair:
            out[0] += pair[0]
            out[1] += pair[1]
    output.append(out)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I prefer codes like this to the comprehensions